# Labels are missing in getting started example for HERE Maps API for Javascript in Chrome 79

Tags: here-api

The code is taken right from the bottom of the "get started" [page](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/get-started.html). The only change is the API key replacement.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 640px; height: 480px" id="mapContainer"></div>
    <script>
      // Initialize the platform object:
      var platform = new H.service.Platform({
        'apikey': '{YOUR_APIKEY}'
      });

      // Obtain the default map types from the platform object
      var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();

      // Instantiate (and display) a map object:
      var map = new H.Map(
        document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
        maptypes.vector.normal.map,
        {
          zoom: 10,
          center: { lng: 13.4, lat: 52.51 }
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is what it looks like in Chrome 79 on Linux Debian:
[image]

Compare with the same page in Firefox 68 on Linux Debian:
[image]

Is this a bug? Can someone please give any troubleshooting/workaround tips?

Comment: It works correctly on chrome version 78.0.3904.108, operating system is MAC. Does it impact only version 79.Can you please try clearing the cache and render again

Comment: Please note the "disable cache" tick in the dev console on my first screenshot. I cleared the cache manually and tried again - same result. I tried opening in incognito mode - same result. Btw the problem can be observed right on the example page on the official website: https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/maps/map-at-specified-location.

Comment: Are you still having this issue, or has it been solved?

Comment: @Tomas, I'm still having the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We try to run this example on Linux Debian env. It worked fine. Can you please share the chrome wget that you have used to install the chrome.

Sharing the screenshot here:

[image]

Comment: I followed this guide: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-google-chrome-web-browser-on-debian-9/ to install Chrome initially. Then I simply updated it from the Google repository added during the installation. My current version is: Version 79.0.3945.79 (Official Build) (64-bit). Linux Debian version is 9 (stretch)